# Powershell Script to change the font of word docs

Tags: powershell, ms-word

Hi I am trying to create a script that changes the font of all word docs in a specific folder, I have managed to create one that changes the font for 1 document but cannot work out how to do this for all files my script is below

```
$Folder = Read-Host "Select Folder name"
$test = Test-Path C:\Users\andy.burton\Desktop\Layouts\$Folder\
$File = @
("0.bil","0.est","0.lbl","1.arm","1.bil","1.crd","1.env","1.est","1.frm","1.gp",
"1.hos","1.ins","1.lbl","1.lc","1.lmr","1.mls","1.NON","1.OP","1.pat","1.PRS
","1.rcl","1.rec","1.rmd","1.stm","10.pat","10.rec","11.pat","11.rec","12.pa
t","12.rec","13.pat","13.rec","14.PAT","14.rec","15.pat","16.pat","17.pat","18.pat","2.arm","2.bil","2.env","2.est","2.frm","2.gp","2.hos","2.ins","2.lbl","2.lc","2.lmr","2.mls","2.NON","2.pat","2.rcl","2.rec","2.rmd","2.stm","3.arm","3.bil","3.env","3.est","3.gp","3.hos","3.ins","3.lbl","3.lc","3.lmr","3.NON","3.pat","3.rec","3.rmd","3.STM","4.arm","4.bil","4.env","4.est","4.gp","4.hos","4.ins","4.lbl","4.lc","4.lmr","4.non","4.pat","4.rec","4.rmd","4.STM","5.arm","5.bil","5.env","5.est","5.gp","5.hos","5.ins","5.lbl","5.lc","5.lmr","5.non","5.pat","5.rec","5.rmd","6.bil","6.env","6.est","6.lbl","6.pat","6.rec","7.env","7.lbl","7.pat","7.rec","8.ENV","8.LBL","8.pat","8.rec","9.env","9.lbl","9.pat","9.rec","acchead.doc","address.lbl","apptreminder.email","apptreminder.sms","BMIBOOK.FRM","BUPA.OCR","clinicprint.rep","clinicprint2.rep","clinicprint2B.rep","clinicprint2C.rep","CLUB.BIL","Consent1.doc","consent2.doc","DEPOSIT.REC","ebs021.doc","ebs022.doc","EBS023.DOC","FConsent1.DOC","FEBS021.DOC","FEBS023.DOC","GP.OP","HCABOOK.FRM","InvCen.doc","InvFoot.doc","INVOICE.LBL","InvoiceGrid.doc","InvoiceGridNonVat.doc","InvoiceGridVAT.doc","InvoiceTotals.doc","InvoiceTotalsNonVAT.doc","InvoiceTotalsVAT.doc","J8160-95.LBL","J8160.LBL","J8162-95.LBL","J8162.LBL","J8163-95.LBL","J8163.LBL","J8165-95.LBL","J8165.LBL","J8360-95.LBL","J8360.LBL","J8362-95.LBL","J8362.LBL","J8363-95.LBL","J8363.LBL","J8365-95.LBL","J8365.LBL","J8560-95.LBL","J8560.LBL","J8562-95.LBL","J8562.LBL","J8563-95.LBL","J8563.LBL","J8565-95.LBL","J8565.LBL","L7160-95.LBL","L7160.LBL","L7161-95.LBL","L7161.LBL","L7162-95.LBL","L7162.LBL","L7163-95.LBL","L7163.LBL","L7164-95.LBL","L7164.LBL","L7165-95.LBL","L7165.LBL","L7166-95.LBL","L7166.LBL","L7167-95.LBL","L7167.LBL","L7168-95.LBL","L7168.LBL","L8162-95.LBL","letfoot.doc","lethead.doc","MC.BIL","NHS.PRS","NUFFBOOK.FRM","OPNOTE.OP","RecCen.doc","RECEIPT2.CC","ReceiptTotals.doc","recfoot.doc","remfoot.doc","shoulder1.jpg","shoulder2.jpg","TDL.FRM","TDL2.FRM","theatreprint.rep","VOUCHER2.CC")



if($test -eq $False) {

Copy-Item -Path 'C:\Users\andy.burton\desktop\Layouts\Arial 10' -Destination C:\Users\andy.burton\Desktop\Layouts\$Folder\ -Recurse


$file.ForEach({ 


$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

$Word.Visible = $False

$Doc = $word.Documents.Open()

$Selection = $word.Selection

$Doc.Select()

$Selection.Font.Name = "Calibri"

$Selection.Font.Size = 11

$Doc.Close()

$Word.Quit()

})


}


Else {Write-Warning "Folder Already Exists"}
```

Comment: How is this failing, and what evidence of its failure are you seeing?

Comment: Originally I had $Doc = $word.Documents.Open("C:\Users\andy.burton\Desktop\Layouts\$Folder\Layouts\1.PAT") which worked fine to open that particular document but I cant work out what to put to open all docs I tried $Doc = $word.Documents.Open() but that didn't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use a Foreach loop and loop through your `$File` array. You may also want to rename `$File` to `$Files`

```
foreach($file in $Files)
{
     # peform font change here
}
```

Comment: I tried that and got the error Select Folder name: Andy
Error while invoking Open. A required parameter was omitted.
At line:16 char:1
+ $Doc = $word.Documents.Open()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:18 char:1
+ $Doc.Select()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: I think this line is the issue $Doc = $word.Documents.Open() but I'm not sure what to put in the () so that it opens each file

Comment: During your loop you will want to generate the path each time fresh. So using your array you use that information to create the path and place it into the `.Open()` method

Comment: amazing worked perfectly thanks again Jason 2nd time you've helped me out

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you. Feel free to upvote the answer if it helps :)

Comment: I did up vote both the answer you have me but my votes don't show yet

Answer (score 0):

I had a need to change the font of a bunch of word documents in a share and the internet seems to point back to this post for results and references about changing the font of an entire word document using powershell. This code and answer did not show it very clearly so I contribute this code. This code gets the word documents in a folder that match the keywords you list in the $Files section, then changes the font to whatever you put in the $Selection.Font.Name = section. I modified the original code from this post to build this and I have already tested it on a local folder as well as a server share. Please let me know if it can be approved upon. For instance it would be nice to output to screen each file that is being changed.

```
$Folder = "\\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER\"
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Recurse -Include *misc*.doc, *.misc*.docx, *Misc*.docx, *Misc*.doc, *MISC.docx, *MISC*.doc, *test*.doc, *test*.docx, whatever.doc

foreach($File in $Files)
{
    $Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $Word.Visible = $false
    $Doc = $Word.Documents.Open($File.FullName)
    $Selection = $Word.Selection
    $Doc.Select()
    $Selection.Font.Name = "Verdana Pro SemiBold"
    $Doc.Close()
    $Word.Quit()
}

Write-Warning "Finshed With Font Change"
```